# Vectorize the procedure of finding max values for splited numpy sub-arrays

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Given a 1d numpy array `arr` and an indices array `ind`,

```
numpy.split(arr, ind)
```

returns the list of divided sub-arrays of `arr` by `ind`. We may use the Python `for` loop to get the max values for all the sub-arrays.

For example,

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(12)
ind = np.array([3, 5, 9])
sub_arrays = np.split(arr, ind) 
# [array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 4]), array([5, 6, 7, 8]), array([ 9, 10, 11])]
max_values = [sub_array.max() for sub_array in sub_arrays]
# [2, 4, 8, 11]
```

Can we do this in a numpy-style, vectorized way? For example, without splitting `arr` at first.

Comment: What does `ind` look like? Can you give an example along with the version that uses a `for` loop?

Comment: @jared just added some examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`np.maximum.reduceat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html). To get the exact result, you need to have `ind` also include index 0.

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(12)
ind = np.array([3, 5, 9])
max_values = np.maximum.reduceat(arr, np.concatenate(([0], ind)))
print(max_values) # [ 2  4  8 11]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(12)
ind = np.array([3, 5, 9])

# Create indices for reduction
indices = np.concatenate(([0], ind, [arr.size]))

# Use np.maximum.reduceat to find maximum values
max_values = np.maximum.reduceat(arr, indices[:-1])

print(max_values)

[ 2  4  8 11]
```

Comment: sorry for not accepting your nice answer but jared post his answer earlier.